# sprintf adding extra character to char array

Tags: c

I'm coding some program and at one point of my code, I'm browsing a directory. In order to make a string concording to the path and file name, I have this code:

```
char *aux;
aux = (char *) malloc(strlen(directory) + strlen(files[j] + 1));

sprintf(aux, "%s/%s", directory, files[j]);

//Debugging...
char b[100]; sprintf(b, "Path + file: %s\n", aux); write(1, b, strlen(b));
char c[100]; sprintf(c, "File: %s\n", files[j]); write(1, c, strlen(c));
```

When I execute my program, the output I get is:

```
Path + file: ./Path/file.txt!
File: file.txt
```

As you can see, in first output string, file has an extra character (`!`) that doesn't belong to the path nor the file (as you can see in the second output string). I also tried adjusting the malloc size to different values and this still happens. Why?

Comment: Carefully count your required characters, and remember, you need one for the terminator in addition to both strings *and* that separating `'/'` . Now, how big was that malloc? You're program invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: PLease edit the question and show a [mcve].  too many details missing.

Comment: You do not need to cast` malloc` - see [casting malloc bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You need to have space for the EOS char but you're doing it the wrong way. Also, you need space for the `/` you're adding. You want: `aux = malloc(strlen(directory) + strlen(files[j]) + 1 + 1);`

Comment: Indeed, that was it...

Comment: Manually counting the number of characters is bound to lead to errors. That is why GNU libc has `asprintf`, it automatically allocates the correct amount for you. For systems without GNU libc look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159892/using-asprintf-on-windows) for how to implement it yourself.